# python Find the only element appearing once in a sequence using the more efficient way than mine

Tags: python, list

Given a list of numbers, where every number shows up twice except for one number, find that one number.

Example:

```
Input: [4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2]
Output: 1
```

Here's the function signature:

```
def singleNumber(nums):
  # Fill this in.

print singleNumber([4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2])
# 1
```

Could anyone provide an efficient way to search through for the number?

This is the solution of mine:

```
def check(seq):
    element =[]
    for i in seq:
        if i not in element:
            element.append(i)
            if seq.count(i)==1:
                return i
    return('Target not found')
```

Actually, you can see this solution work most efficiently when there is a lot of duplicate of a single element in the sequence and then it can save you from iteraing through the sequence again and again, which is not the case above.My solution even force me to search through two lists(element and seq), which is not efficient enough.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, there is some issue with my Internet connection.

Comment: `min(nums,key=nums.count)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the elements in the list. Since you know there's exactly one element that appears once, it will be the least common element, so:

```py
def singleNumber(nums):
    return Counter(nums).most_common()[-1][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a one-liner, you could use `filter`:

```py
def singleNumber(nums):
    return next(filter(lambda num: nums.count(num) == 1, nums))
```

It's a little complicated, so let's break it down:

First, we determine what the predicate is:
Since we want the first element which appears only once in the list, we know that `nums.count(num)` should be equal to 1.

Next, we can use that function along with a lambda to use it in a filter function which iterates over a given iterable and yields all matching members.

Now, since we know that only 1 of the numbers will match, we only need to return the first number that matches our filter, hence the `next()` around the filter statement. `next()` returns the next item that is returned from the iterator (`filter` in our case).

Comment: This is a fun approach, but highly inefficient as you need to read the whole list again for each element (O(n^2) complexity) due to `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is a generic O(n) solution. It works for any number of unique items.

This is using sets to keep track of the seen and duplicated elements, with a set difference to get the unique items:

```
nums = [4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2]

seen = set()
dup = set()

for i in nums:
    dup.add(i) if i in seen else seen.add(i)

seen-dup
```

Output `{1}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the first element of `nums` that has a `count` of 1. Try the following:

```
def singleNumber(nums):
    for x in nums:
        if nums.count(x) == 1:
            return x

print (singleNumber([4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2]))
```

Output:

```
1
```